# Positional operator not working with feathersjs query update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, feathersjs

I have a problem with update data with feathersjs update function by using a positional operator. I have a following JSON document in mongoDB:

```
{
"name" : "John Jonson",
    "payments" : [
        {
            "year" : 2016,
            "payments" : [
                {
                    "comment" : "",
                    "title" : "1 payment",
                    "amount" : 100,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T15:04:09.647Z")
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "year" : 2015,
            "payments" : [
                {
                    "comment" : "first payment",
                    "title" : "02/04/2015",
                    "amount" : 150,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T15:10:04.499Z")
                },
                {
                    "comment" : "second payment",
                    "title" : "05/06/2015",
                    "amount" : 150,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T15:10:04.499Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I try update this document through push to payments.payments array an object only there where year is 2015:

```
var data = {
      _id: "5a16e032b7a982bc9b7bd7fe",
      payment: {
         "amount": 200,
         "title": "09/02/2016",
         "comment": ""
      }
    }

app.service('payments').update({_id: data._id, "payments.year": 2015}, {$push: { "payments.$.payments": data.payment }}, { "multi": true }, (error, result) => {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(result)
    });
```

After called above function I receive following message:

```
"exception: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: payments.$.payments"
```

but when I use this statement in mongo shell, all is fine:

```
db.payments.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5a16e032b7a982bc9b7bd7fe"), "payments.year": 2015}, {$push: { "payments.$.payments": {"amount":200,"title":"09/02/2016","comment":""}}}, {"multi": true});
```

*** I resolved my problem. I use patch method: ***

```
var query = {_id: data._id, "payments.year": 2015}

app.service('payments').patch(null, {$push: { "payments.$.payments": data.payment }}, { query }, (error, result) => {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(result)
});
```

I have only one question. Why above code works fine but the below code not?

```
app.service('payments').patch(null, {$push: { "payments.$.payments": data.payment }}, {_id: data._id, "payments.year": 2015}, (error, result) => {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` in your working code is using property value shorthand. The feathers mongodb adapter patch method takes a `query` param so try this:

```
app.service('payments').patch(null, {$push: { "payments.$.payments": data.payment }}, {query: { _id: data._id, "payments.year": 2015 }}, (error, result) => {
  console.log(error)
  console.log(result)
});
```

Comment: Was this helpful @SeaDog?